# Why does .getFullYear() return 2017 for the date "2018-01-01"

Tags: javascript

I noticed that if I convert "2018-01-01" to date format I get `2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` and If I use the [.getFullYear()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getfullyear.asp) method, it returns `2017`. Why is this?

`new Date("2018-01-01").getFullYear()` returns `2017`

```js
var d = new Date("2018-01-01");
console.log(d.getFullYear());
```

Comment: the date is in UTC, whereas .getFullYear is using your time zone

Comment: Could you share the actual line of code that yields 2017, please? We are not psychics 

Comment: That code produces 2018 for me, because, **timezones**

Comment: `.getUTCFullYear()` solved it. def was timezone.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to your local timezone, try getUTCFullYear() instead.